# How to create an activity that resembles a dialog but has some specific features like scrolling off the screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-styles

I'm trying to create an activity that looks somewhat like a dialog. These are some features that I want to achieve:

1. Doesn't take up the entire screen
2. You can see the previous activity in the background
3. The background should darken
4. Parts can scroll off the screen
5. It should be dismissed when clicking on the background (where the previous activity is visible)

When I was searching for using activities as dialogs most people seem to suggest using a dialog style for the activity, for example `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`.

```
<style name="ActivityDialog2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

So I tried that and I ended up with what can be seen in [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDmEQ.png) [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGhaG.png) screenshots.

So 1, 2 and 5 have been achieved easily enough. However 3 and 4 not yet. 3 should also be easy enough, however I can't figure out how to do 4 with this style.

Because I couldn't figure that out I opted for another option: Changing a normal activity style to do what I want.

```
<style name="ActivityDialog1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

I ended up with what can be seen in [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9V4O.jpg) [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfDrr.png) screenshots. I really dig the style of this (except for the opening animation). But now I'm running into another issue. I can't seem to get it dismissed when clicking the background. The most simply idea I had was setting a click listener to the scrollview and calling `onBackPressed()`, but it simply won't register.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve all the properties that I'm aiming for?

I've created a repository with a sample application with my current ideas and implementations [here](https://github.com/fdorssers/Activity-Dialog-Example) for those that are interested.

Edit: I have managed to implement a method to dismiss the activity. I've added a `LinearLayout` to the `ScrollView` setting it to `match_parent` and I've set the `ScrollView` to fill the viewport. Next I only had set `clickable` to `false` on the `CardView` and I was able to add a listener to the `LinearLayout` to dismiss the activity.

Comment: I think your looking for a Fragment. Specifically a Dialog Fragment. Have you tried them yet?

Comment: I did try them after you and @RichLuick suggested them and it has some of the behaviours I want, but I also haven't been able to achieve some of the other behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

So what your trying to do isn't exactly good practice, trying to use an activity as a Dialog. They have created Fragments just for this, specifically Dialog Fragments. Fragments are basically UI components with their own functionality which are part of an activity.

More on that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Okay so create a new Fragment which extends Dialog Fragment like so:

```
public class NewDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public NewDialogFragment() {
       //constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_dialog, false); //inflate the xml layout

        //put your code for the fragment here        

        return view;
    }
}
```

The xml layout works the same way as in an activity so you should be able to use the same layout file.

And now in the main activity you are launching the dialog in:

```
//on button click or whenever you want to launch it
NewDialogFragment fragment = new NewDialogFragment();
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: I'm aware that it is not ideal, but I haven't found another way to achieve the behaviours that I'd like to have. I did implement your suggestion and it works quite well, thank you for that. However the dialog is still limited to what is on screen, a scrollview will simply scroll within the bounds of the dialog instead of going off the screen like in the third and fourth screenshot of my post. Would you happen to know a way to achieve this effect using a DialogFragment?

Comment: Can you post the xml of your layout?

Comment: The entire project is available in the repository that is linked in the post. [This](https://github.com/fdorssers/Activity-Dialog-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_dialog_4.xml) is the specific layout. It also still has some issues with the width that I haven't fixed yet.

Comment: Instead of match parent for the width and height, try a custom dimension and see what that gives you.